# Custom styling mat-form-field inside a mat-toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

Just playing around with the latest version of Angular Material, and am attempting to add a search input to a toolbar that has a primary color applied:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" color="primary">
        <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
        <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput />
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

I need to custom style the mat-form-field instance, in particular, remove the `whitesmoke` background color applied by the prebuilt theme I am using in my example. Plus I will probably want to change the text color, etc.

I started playing with `::ng-deep` which I know is deprecated

```
:host  mat-form-field {
  > ::ng-deep div {
    background-color: unset;
  }
  background-color: unset;
  input {
    background-color: unset;
  }
}
```

Whilst this got me further, I know it's not the right way -

What is the correct approach here to achieve this kind of thing, please?

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leqcax?file=src/app/toolbar-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a separate `theme.css` somewhere in your src/assets folder, then import it in your angular.json file styles. You won't need ::ng-deep anymore to style material elements.

Answer (score 1):

In your **styles.scss** you can override variables and clases of a component simply adding the "selector of the component" (in this case `toolbar-overview-example`)

```
toolbar-overview-example {
  --mdc-theme-primary: white;
  .mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-text-field__input {
    color: white;
  }
  mat-form-field.mat-primary
    .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay {
    background-color: white;
    top: 1rem;
  }
  .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled)
    .mdc-line-ripple::before {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 225, 255, 0.42);
  }
  .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):hover
    .mdc-line-ripple::before {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 225, 255, 0.87);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leqcax-19rnad?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-overview-example.html)

Comment: hi, could you explain the reason why this works when you put the css code in the styles.css file, but it doesn't work when you put the code in the component's css file?

Answer (score -1):

```
   .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  outline: 0px solid purple !important;
}
```

So you remove it when it's normal, I still don't understand how to do it when it's active or invalid

Comment: Please use english only, as [all content on Stack Overflow must be written in English](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)